# Remove some characters between numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I retrieved address which i need to format a part of it using PHP

```
$address="testbuz<br>
Test Test <br>
Test
1<br>
2fdd aa, city<br>
Belgium<br>
T: 1234567890
<br>BTW: BE-04-84-71-02-01";
```

I need to format the part after **BTW** like
BTW: **BE014149111**

There can have other symbols as **separators like spaces stars hash**, so which need to show numbers after BE without any space or symbol

so the output like

```
 $address="testbuz<br>
Test Test <br>
Test
1<br>
2fdd aa, city<br>
Belgium<br>
    T: 1234567890
    <br>BTW: BE0414150211";
```

Someone know how to do this with PHP please, i appreciate your help.

Note:-

**it not just dashes, it may be vary, and i cannot replace all address - symbols, it should check and replace after BTW: BE**

Thank You

Comment: `str_replace('-','',$string);`

Comment: it not just dashes, it may be vary, and i cannot replace all address - symbols, it should check and replace after BTW: BE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$address="Horecaworld<br>
Test Test <br>
Test
1<br>
2911 EA, Rotterdam<br>
Belgium<br>
T: 1234567890
<br>BTW: BE-04#64/91.02|11";

$result = preg_replace_callback('/^(.+BTW: BE)(.+)$/m', function ($m) {
                        return $m[1] . preg_replace('/\D/', '', $m[2]);
                    },
                    $address);
echo $result,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
Horecaworld<br>
Test Test <br>
Test
1<br>
2911 EA, Rotterdam<br>
Belgium<br>
T: 1234567890
<br>BTW: BE0464910211
```

Comment: I'm not sure, how does this answer the question exactly? It would just remove `<br>BTW: ` from the string.

Comment: it working for - but when i check using dot ex - BE-04-64-91-02.11 it remains dot

Comment: i need to remove anything except numbers after BE-04-64-91-02.11, Thanks a lot

Comment: @SunethKalhara:see my last edit. It removes everything that is not a digit.

Comment: seems like working but it also remove BE :) "BTW: 0464910211 " can we keep that and remove the things after BE please, so it will looks like "BTW: BE0464910211 " Thank You

Comment: @SunethKalhara:Fixed, it now keeps `BE`

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using functions [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php). Try this:

```
$prefix = strstr($address, 'BTW: ', true); // Contains string until BTW: appears
$editable = strstr($address, 'BTW: '); // Contains string after BTW: appears
$editable = str_replace('-','',$editable); // Replace all occurences of - 
$result = $prefix.$editable; // Final string
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it can replace - but i cannot guess there have only - symbol, it can be .,*,space,+,letter or any

Answer (score 1):

With `preg_replace` and a `\G` based pattern:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|BTW:\h*)[A-Z0-9]{2}\K[^A-Z0-9\r\n]~', '', $str);
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/BYqukJ/1)

The `\G` anchor matches the position after the previous match and forces successive results that use this branch to be contiguous.
The `\K` feature removes the substring matched with the left part of the pattern from the match result. This way, only the character that matches `[^A-Z0-9\r\n]` is removed.

Note that starting a pattern with an alternation isn't very efficient since the regex engine needs to test each branch for each position in the string until one of the branch succeeds.
However, you can drastically reduce this work with a little trick to quickly skip all substrings without B until `"BTW:"`.

```
~(?:\G(?!\A)|[^B]*(*SKIP)BTW:\h*)[A-Z0-9]{2}\K[^A-Z0-9\r\n]~
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/BYqukJ/2)

Comment: Thank you for the answer